# Простой filepicker на javascript

Tags: javascript, файлы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, простой filepicker на javascript, в котором можно выбрать один из файлов, находящихся в определенной папке на сервере или ввести ссылку на свой файл. Обращаю внимание на то, что в filepicker не должно быть возможности загружать файлы на сервер.

Comment: непонятно, что именно вы хотите. js тут мало при чем.

Comment: @eicto, почему же мало при чем? Тут много чего на js http://www.roxyfileman.com/demo

Comment: @mountpoint какой ужас... (я про roxy)

Comment: @eicto, внутренности возможно ужасны, а так вполне неплохой файлменеджер

Comment: не, выглядит кошмарно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант хорош, но я к тому времени уже решил проблему при помощи базового редактора, в моем случае это ckeditor с модулем ckfinder. Пришлось скопировать его лишний раз и в конфиге ckfinder настройки. Оказалось все очень просто ;)

Answer (score 1):

Вот скрипт, который создаёт простой file picker и добавляет его в вашу веб страницу:

```
var fp = document.createElement("input");
fp.type="file";
document.body.appendChild(fp);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4zg4153/)